# Как добавить значок последнего релиза к GitLab репозиторию использующего тег?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Имеется проект на GitLab версии 15.1.6-ее, в который необходимо добавить значок (badge) последнего релиза.
Так как знаний в настройке CI/CD для создания релизов в автоматическом режиме у меня нет, то было решено в скрипте *.gitlab-ci.yml* указать, что сборка выполняется только если указан тег.
Другими словами, если указан тег, то выполняются тесты, происходит сборка и загружается на локальный репозиторий [Archiva](https://archiva.apache.org). Теги не используют каких-либо префиксов и являются номерами версий, например 1.2.3, 3.0.5 и т.д..

Файл *.gitlab-ci.yml*:

```yml
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

test_job:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - maven
    - java11
  script:
    - $env:JAVA_HOME=$env:JAVA11_HOME
    - mvn "-DSkipMarkedJUnitTests=true" clean test

deploy_snapshot:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^SNAPSHOT/
  tags:
    - maven
    - java11
  script:
    - $env:JAVA_HOME=$env:JAVA11_HOME
    - mvn "-DSkipMarkedJUnitTests=true" deploy

deploy_release:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - tags
  except:
    - branches
  tags:
    - maven
    - java11
  script:
  - $env:JAVA_HOME=$env:JAVA11_HOME
  - mvn "-DSkipMarkedJUnitTests=true" deploy
```

Далее, в настройках проекта (*General/Badges*), создаю новый значок:

- Name -> Release
- Link -> [http://example.tld/%{project_path}/-/releases](http://example.tld/%%7Bproject_path%7D/-/releases)
- Badge image URL -> [http://example.tld/%{project_path}/-/badges/release.svg](http://example.tld/%%7Bproject_path%7D/-/badges/release.svg)

После чего получаю значок, который отображает последний релиз созданный вручную (*Deployments/Releases -> New release*).

Каким образом можно создать значок, который бы указывал не на последний релиз созданный вручную, а на последний (в идеале старший/больший) тег?